C# .NET set DCD Data Carrier Detect on Serial Line
I need to write a Modem emulation, and so I need to set the DCD "pin" inside my C# .NET application. The SerialPort Class does only have a method for CDHolding, which reads the DCD state.
Does anyone know, if there is any possibility to also set the DCD State?
Thanks

DCD (or CD) is only an input/status notification/reading function on the PC (terminal) side, and cannot be set or changed from application programs or device drivers.
Understanding RS232 Serial Port Communication
SerialPort.CDHolding Property
SerialPort.PinChanged Event
SerialPinChange Enum
If you want to create modem emulation, you will need to define, implement and use your own interfaces and functions rather than using .NET or the Win32 API.
